# Обращение к тегу через CSS

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста как мне обратиться к тегу < li> в моём примере, через CSS.

```
<ul id="menu1" class="menu">
  <li><a href="/1.html">Ссылка</a></li>
  <li><a href="/2.html">Ссылка2</a></li>
</ul>
```

На примере изменения размера шрифта.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.menu li {
    font-size: 16px;
}

#menu1 li {
    font-size: 16px;
}

ul li {
    font-size: 16px;
}

li {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Все четыре варианта обращаются к тэгу li в вашем списке и устанавливают размер шрифта в нём 16px. Можете выбирать любой, а можете применить все сразу (хуже не будет, вдруг какой не сработает).

Comment: интересно за что поставили минус этому ответу? Или кто-то передумал и вернул обратно свой голос?